# Баги со слайдером Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Реализовал слайдер в коде, всё работает, но при наведении на кнопку, которая должна перелистывать картинку, она начинает "беситься"(становится то прозрачной, то нет). Вот [гифка](https://gfycat.com/linearflimsyhoiho) на которой всё видно. Сам код:

```
def slider1(event):
    sht.place(x=580, y=0)

def unslider1(event):
    sht.place_forget()
faad = PhotoImage(file="knq.png")
m2 = ttk.Label(f, image=img2)
sht = ttk.Label(f, image=faad)
m2.bind('<Enter>', slider1)
m2.bind('<Leave>', unslider1)
m2.place(x=310, y=0)
```

Comment: Когда курсор наезжает на кнопку `sht`, это считается событием `<Leave>` для `m2`, поэтому кнопка пропадает.

Answer (score 0):

Мигание происходит из-за того, что для метки `m2` событие, когда курсор наезжает на кнопку слайдера (`sht`) является для нее событием `<Leave>`, поэтому кнопка исчезает. Как только кнопка исчезает - курсор опять оказывается над `m2` (событие `<Enter>`) - кнопка снова появляется. И так по кругу.

Чтобы это не происходило, нужно привязываться не к событиям картинок, а к событиям родительского контрола. В примере ниже - к событиям фрейма:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def on_enter(event):
    sht.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.0, relwidth=0.1, relheight=1.0)


def on_leave(event):
    sht.place_forget()


root = tk.Tk()

f = tk.Frame(root, width=500, height=200)
f.pack()
f.pack_propagate(False)

f.bind('<Enter>', on_enter)
f.bind('<Leave>', on_leave)

m2 = tk.Label(f, text="Тут какая-то картинка", bg="lightblue")
m2.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relwidth=0.5, relheight=1.0)

m2 = tk.Label(f, text="Тут какая-то другая картинка", bg="lightgreen")
m2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.0, relwidth=0.5, relheight=1.0)

sht = tk.Label(f, text='>', bg='lightgray', foreground='gray', font='20')

root.mainloop()
```

Если нужно, чтобы кнопка появлялась именно при наведении на правую картинку, то кнопку можно разместить внутри самой картинки, и привязаться к событиям картинки:

```
m2 = tk.Label(f, text="Тут какая-то другая картинка", bg="lightgreen")
m2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.0, relwidth=0.5, relheight=1.0)

sht = tk.Label(m2, text='>', bg='lightgray', foreground='gray', font='20')

m2.bind('<Enter>', on_enter)
m2.bind('<Leave>', on_leave)
```